# can not open software center

Tags: software-center

```
abdul@abdul-Inspiron-3521:~$ software-center
2013-06-02 21:53:50,082 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
2013-06-02 21:53:50,088 - softwarecenter.db.database - INFO - open() database: path=None use_axi=True use_agent=True
2013-06-02 21:53:50,089 - softwarecenter.db.database - ERROR - failed to add apt-xapian-index
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/database.py", line 183, in _get_new_xapiandb
    softwarecenter.paths.APT_XAPIAN_INDEX_DB_PATH)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xapian/__init__.py", line 3666, in __init__
    _xapian.Database_swiginit(self,_xapian.new_Database(*args))
DatabaseOpeningError: Couldn't stat '/var/lib/apt-xapian-index/index' (No such file or directory)
2013-06-02 21:53:50,261 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - Could not get usefulness from server, no username in config file
2013-06-02 21:53:50,427 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - show_available_packages: search_text is '', app is None.
2013-06-02 21:53:50,444 - softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache - INFO - aptcache.open()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/pkginfo_impl/aptcache.py", line 243, in open
    self._cache = apt.Cache(GtkMainIterationProgress())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 102, in __init__
    self.open(progress)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 145, in open
    self._cache = apt_pkg.Cache(progress)
SystemError: E:Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_binary-amd64_Packages (1), E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
2013-06-02 21:53:50,784 - softwarecenter.db.categories - WARNING - sort by cataloged time requested but your a-x-i does not seem to support that yet
2013-06-02 21:53:51,173 - softwarecenter.db.categories - WARNING - sort by cataloged time requested but your a-x-i does not seem to support that yet
2013-06-02 21:53:51,277 - softwarecenter.db.categories - WARNING - sort by cataloged time requested but your a-x-i does not seem to support that yet
2013-06-02 21:53:51,327 - softwarecenter.db.categories - WARNING - sort by cataloged time requested but your a-x-i does not seem to support that yet
2013-06-02 21:53:51,378 - softwarecenter.db.categories - WARNING - sort by cataloged time requested but your a-x-i does not seem to support that yet
2013-06-02 21:53:51,434 - softwarecenter.db.enquire - ERROR - _get_estimate_nr_apps_and_nr_pkgs failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/enquire.py", line 115, in _get_estimate_nr_apps_and_nr_pkgs
    tmp_matches = enquire.get_mset(0, len(self.db), None, xfilter)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/appfilter.py", line 89, in __call__
    if (not pkgname in self.cache and
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/pkginfo_impl/aptcache.py", line 263, in __contains__
    return self._cache.__contains__(k)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__contains__'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 176, in <module>
    app.run(args)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 1420, in run
    self.show_available_packages(args)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 1350, in show_available_packages
    self.view_manager.set_active_view(ViewPages.AVAILABLE)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/session/viewmanager.py", line 154, in set_active_view
    view_widget.init_view()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/panes/availablepane.py", line 168, in init_view
    self.apps_filter)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/catview_gtk.py", line 237, in __init__
    self.build(desktopdir)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/catview_gtk.py", line 504, in build
    self._build_homepage_view()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/catview_gtk.py", line 271, in _build_homepage_view
    self._append_top_rated()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/catview_gtk.py", line 417, in _append_top_rated
    top_rated_cat = self._update_top_rated_content()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/catview_gtk.py", line 404, in _update_top_rated_content
    docs = top_rated_cat.get_documents(self.db)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/categories.py", line 124, in get_documents
    nonblocking_load=False)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/enquire.py", line 317, in set_query
    self._blocking_perform_search()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/enquire.py", line 212, in _blocking_perform_search
    matches = enquire.get_mset(0, self.limit, None, xfilter)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/appfilter.py", line 89, in __call__
    if (not pkgname in self.cache and
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/pkginfo_impl/aptcache.py", line 263, in __contains__
    return self._cache.__contains__(k)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__contains__'
abdul@abdul-Inspiron-3521:~$
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Have you looked at some other related post in the site?

Comment: I have the same problem and @Marc answer solved it , but this problem is happening to other applications ,any idea why this happens ?

Answer (score 0):

Did it work before?

You could always use apt-get to re-install software-center:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-center
```